# How to pass variable to Pandas merge left_on parameter?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new on Python.
I have this code:

```
on_left = "id,flg_active"
on_right = "id_test,flg_new_active"
result = pd.merge(left, right, how= how.lower(), left_on=[on_left],right_on=[on_right])
```

This is the error I receive

```
KeyError: 'id,flg_active'
```

Instead, the code run correctly in this way:

```
result = pd.merge(left, right, how= how.lower(), left_on=['id','flg_active'],right_on=['id_test','flg_new_active'])
```

Can someone help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

**EDIT**

This is the solution:

```
on_left = []
on_right = []
on_left.append("id")
on_left.append("flg_active")
on_right.append("id_test")
on_right.append("flg_new_active")

result = pd.merge(left, right, how= how.lower(), left_on=on_left,right_on=on_right)
```

Comment: Have you tried using what works in the merge to create the variables?  like `on_left = ['id','flg_active']`

Comment: You could also do `left_on=on_left.split(',')` to create the list from your string.

Answer (score 0):

So the question is: **What's the difference between `"id,flg_active"` and `['id','flg_active']`?**

`"id,flg_active"` is a string containing some alphabetic characters and a comma. If you pass this to the `left_on` parameter, pandas will look for a single column called exactly this: `id,flg_active`. But it won't find it, hence the error.

`['id','flg_active']` is a list of two strings `id` and `flg_active`. If you pass this to the `left_on` parameter, pandas will look for 2 columns called `id` and `flg_active`, respectively to merge the rows on a compound key.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
on_left = ["id", "flg_active"]
on_right = ["id_test", "flg_new_active"]
result = pd.merge(left, right, how= how.lower(), left_on=on_left,right_on=on_right)
```